# Carousel component based on progress moving bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have the following mockup: [image]

Until now, I managed to do the following which is pretty close: https://codesandbox.io/s/codepen-with-react-forked-16t6rv?file=/src/components/TrendingNFTs.js

I have the following problems that I'm trying to tackle:

1. When pressing the next and previous buttons, the component seems to reset, what I want is to stop there in case the element is the last on the list
2. I'm find the progress bar below the cards with the arrows hard to implement and I want to ask if you guys have ever seems something that comes close to this.

Thanks in advance, if something is willing to help me with some ideas at least.

Answer (score 0):

You can take let count = 0 at the start and update rest of the code as

```
const shiftPrev = (copy) => {
    let lastcard = copy.pop();
    if (count > 0) {
      copy.splice(0, 0, lastcard);
      setCarouselItems(copy);
    }
  };



const shiftNext = (copy) => {
    let firstcard = copy.shift();
    if (count < copy.length) {
      copy.splice(copy.length, 0, firstcard);
      setCarouselItems(copy);
    }
  };
```

The logic is you take the initial count (you can also keep your count in state but on setState it will re-render which might cause performance issue later)

Also, please consider adding css and the initial card its displaying on UI and set your start/end count accordingly.